# wait for promise before exit process

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to run a NodeJS code that reads some data fields from an array, use them to do a database query to check if the data is duplicate before inserting them into the corresponding table.

My NodeJS code will be called from a PHP script so I need to know when it ends this is why I need to add process.exit(0) somewhere. The problem I have is that if I add it, the script is terminated and my promise never gets the time to send back the result.

Here is my code:

```
var bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        result.forEach((row, index, array) => {
            var escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
            var checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as found FROM data WHERE field1 = " + escaped[0] + " AND field2 = " + escaped[1] + " AND field3 = " + escaped[2] + " AND field4 = " + escaped[3] + " AND field5 = " + escaped[4] + " AND field6 = " + escaped[5] + " AND field7  = " + escaped[6] + ";";
            conn.query(checkQuery, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error checking row for duplicate");
                    console.log(checkQuery);
                    process.exit(1);
                } else {
                    if (res[0].found == 0) {
                        var query = " (";
                        var escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
                        var csv = escaped.join(',');
                        query += csv;
                        query += ")";
                        query += row !== _.last(result) ? ',' : ';';
                        console.log(query);//This will change to inserting the data to the table
                    }else{
                        console.log("Duplicate found!");
                    }
                }
            });
            if (index === array.length -1) resolve();
        });
    });

    bar.then(() => {
        console.log('All done!');
        process.exit(0);
    });
```

If I remove `process.exit(0);` I see **"All done"** first then `console.log(query)` result.
If I add it, the script is terminated and I see **"All done"** only.

Is there a better approach to do this task please?

Thanks.

Comment: You're not waiting for all `con.query()` calls to finish before resolving your promise.  DO NOT mix plain asynchronous callbacks like `con.query()` with promises.  Instead, use the built-in promise interface in your database for `con.query()` and use `await` or `Promise.all()` to track them, get rid of `.forEach()` which is not async-aware and use a plain `for` loop and then you can track when everything is done and call `process.exit()` only when it is all done.

Comment: FYI, when `index === array.length -1` all that means is that you've sent all your `con.query()` calls - it doesn't mean anything about when they are all done.

Comment: Also, please show the entire function here, not just part of it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this code?  What result are you trying to communicate to whom?  All this code does now is `console.log()` things.  In assessing how to fix it the right way, we need to know what result you're trying to get and to whom you want it communicated to.  Do you want a resolved value that the caller can get?  Do you want to abort the code as soon as you find `res[0].found == 0` or do you want to run all the queries to completion?

Comment: Sorry I though my code was clear. All I'm trying to do is to loop trough result variable that is an array that has fields values in it and check against the database, if the query run finds duplicates, it just ignores the data (showing duplicates message) and if the data is new, it inserts it (which I represented with a console.log(query))

Comment: That is the function I'm running, what is missing is just a file read and content put in the result variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to wait for a promise before the application exits.

```
class Waiter {
  private timeout: any
  constructor() {
    this.waitLoop()
  }
  private waitLoop():void {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => { this.waitLoop() }, 100 * 1000)
  }
  okToQuit():void {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }
}

// Your app.

const appPromise:Promise<any> = ...

const w = new Waiter()
appPromise.finally(() => {
  console.log("Quitting")
  w.okToQuit()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple asynchronous operations in a loop and tracking when everything is done is just way, way, way easier if you use promises for all the individual asynchronous operation rather than trying to track asynchronous operations that use plain callbacks.

You don't say exactly what your database is, but if it's mysql, then there is a `mysql2/promise` driver that natively supports promises and that would be my recommendation to switch to that.  Then you can directly use a promise returned from `.query()`.  But, without the info about your specific database driver, I've shown how to manually promisify `.query()`.

Then, the looping code can use a `for` loop and `await` to sequence the database calls so it's easy to know when they are all complete.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

async function someFunc() {
    // other code here

    // promisify conn.query (or use promise interface directly from the database)
    conn.queryP = promisify(conn.query);

    try {
        for (const row of result) {
            const escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
            const checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as found FROM data WHERE field1 = " + escaped[0] + " AND field2 = " +
                escaped[1] + " AND field3 = " + escaped[2] + " AND field4 = " + escaped[3] + " AND field5 = " +
                escaped[4] + " AND field6 = " + escaped[5] + " AND field7  = " + escaped[6] + ";";
            let res = await con.queryP(checkQuery);
            if (res[0].found == 0) {
                const csv = _.map(row, mysql.escape).join(',');
                const terminator = row !== _.last(result) ? ',' : ';';
                const query = " (" + csv + ")" + terminator;
                console.log(query); //This will change to inserting the data to the table
            } else {
                console.log("Duplicate found!");
            }

        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error checking row for duplicate: ", checkQuery);
        console.log(e);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log('All done!');
    process.exit(0);
}
```

The code appears to be trying to build a query inside the loop where each iteration of the loop will add-on to the next (that's what `_.last(result) ? ',' : ';';` look like anyway).  If that's the case, then the query variable has to be moved outside the loop so it can build from one iteration of the loop to the next.  But, you don't show what you're really trying to do with that query so you're on your own for that part.

Answer (score 0):

you decide how many promises will go out before hand and then count them as they resolve, then exit

in this example the same principle is applied but it has callback functions instead of promises. For promises you would call a count function from the .then() or .finally(), and the count function will decide whether it is time to exit

mongoose example from a javascript server:

```
let g_DB = null;

//init mongoose
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const connectionParams = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};
const connStr1 = "mongodb+srv://XX:XX@clusterXX.XX.mongodb.net/XX? 
    retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(connStr1, connectionParams)
    .then(handleConnection())
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error:", err));
//end script

//handleConnection - start on successful response from mongoose connection
function handleConnection(msg) {
  console.log("mongoose has connected to Mongo Atlas successfully");

  g_DB = mongoose.connection;
  g_DB.once("open", function () {
    console.log(
      "mongoose has connected to Mongo Atlas Cluster using database XX"
    );
    doTest();
  });
}

//---------------------------------------------------
function doTest() {
  console.log("test-05: create 500 books");

  //---- MODEL ----
  const _schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    quantity: Number,
  });

  //g_DB is a mongoose connection set earlier in the script
  const _model = g_DB.model("book_schema", _schema, "bookstore");

  let loopcount = 500;
  let waitcount = loopcount;
  for (let i = 0; i < loopcount; i++) {
    _m = new _model({
      name: `WHY MAKE 500 BOOKS ${new Date().toISOString()}`,
      price: 200,
      quantity: 2000,
    });

    _m.save((e, x) => {
      if (e) return console.error(e);
      console.log(x, `waitcount: ${--waitcount}`);
      if (!waitcount) doExit();
    });
  }
}

//--
function doExit() {
  console.log("exit from server");
  process.exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Reject/Resolve to manage promise in Nodejs

When your task fulfils your request send result with resolve(); and if its failing use reject();

In your case you are not managing promise properly that's why it's running asynchronously, better to use following way with the proper returns.

```
var bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return result.forEach((row, index, array) => {
        var escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
        var checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as found FROM data WHERE field1 = " + escaped[0] + " AND field2 = " + escaped[1] + " AND field3 = " + escaped[2] + " AND field4 = " + escaped[3] + " AND field5 = " + escaped[4] + " AND field6 = " + escaped[5] + " AND field7  = " + escaped[6] + ";";
        return conn.query(checkQuery, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error checking row for duplicate");
                console.log(checkQuery);
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                if (res[0].found == 0) {
                    var query = " (";
                    var escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
                    var csv = escaped.join(',');
                    query += csv;
                    query += ")";
                    query += row !== _.last(result) ? ',' : ';';
                    console.log(query);//This will change to inserting the data to the table
                    return resolve(query)
                } else {
                    console.log("Duplicate found!");
                    return reject('Duplicate Found');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

bar.then((data) => {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

In above code I am returning query + resolve/reject so it makes better to run in more synchronised way.
  `return conn.query(checkQuery, function (err, res) {`

Plus, while processing this promise I am handling with `.then((data)`  so I can handle that resolve values here.

```
bar.then((data) => {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

Note: If you are rejecting any promise it won't be available in above .then block you'll find this reject in catch block so code will be changed in following way.

```
bar.then((data) => {
    console.log('All done!');
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves any of the main problems this code has.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```js
(async () => {

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        result.forEach((row, index, array) => {
            var escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
            var checkQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as found FROM data WHERE field1 = 
    " + escaped[0] + " AND field2 = " + escaped[1] + " AND field3 = " + 
escaped[2] + " AND field4 = " + escaped[3] + " AND field5 = " + escaped[4] + " AND field6 = " + escaped[5] + " AND field7  = " + escaped[6] + ";";
            conn.query(checkQuery, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error checking row for duplicate");
                    console.log(checkQuery);
                    process.exit(1);
                } else {
                    if (res[0].found == 0) {
                        var query = " (";
                        var escaped = _.map(row, mysql.escape);
                        var csv = escaped.join(',');
                        query += csv;
                        query += ")";
                        query += row !== _.last(result) ? ',' : ';';
                        console.log(query);//This will change to inserting the data to the table
                    }else{
                        console.log("Duplicate found!");
                    }
                }
            });
            if (index === array.length -1) resolve();
        });
    });


        console.log('All done!');

})();
```

You don't even need to call the process.exit(0) because the code will always terminate when the job is done :)